# Is get_template_part() taking into account localization?

Tags: wordpress, localization

I am using get_template_part() to dynamically insert wordpress pages. I have (m)qTranslate installed but I can not get any other language than the default one with get_template_part(). The __() and _e() are also not translated.

get_template_part() code:

```
$q_config['language'] = $_POST['lang'];
$post_id = $_POST['postId'];
$page_data = get_post( $post_id );   

ob_start();
get_template_part( 'page-template/page', $page_data->post_name );
$output .= ob_get_clean();
ob_end_flush();
```

template code example:

```
<div>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="isotope-list">
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
     if (in_category( get_category_by_slug( 'designs' )->term_id )) { 
        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  
        $termsString = ""; 
            foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { 
                $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; 
            }
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item">
            <span class="fs-<?php echo $post->ID; ?> ?>"></span>
            <div><?php the_title();?></div>
            <div class="thumbmail">
                <?php 
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail-size', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                    echo '<img src="'.$thumb_url.'"/>';
                ?>
            </div>
            <span class="description name"><?php _e( 'Click to see more', 'sp' ); ?></span>
            </a>
        </div> 
    <?php } 
    endwhile;  ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

In function.php I have:

```
load_child_theme_textdomain('sp', get_stylesheet_directory().'/languages');
```

Does anybody know if get_template_part() can get the localization and how?

Answer (score 0):

I have just replaced the mqtranslate (deprecated) plugin with qtranslate-X and the translation is working fine again with get_template_part().